# How to get the value from this json string in java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the below json string as output,

```
{"message":"Error while updating","success":false}
```

And i am trying to get the json object out of it by using,

```
String resp = "{"message":"Error while updating",
                   "success":false}";
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(resp);
log.info("jObject-success: "+ jObject.getString("success").toString());
```

The above line throws "success" is not found in the response error. What am i missing here?

Comment: instead of getting the json output in a string use direct json to get its object,as when you assign the output to a string it will become a string and not remain a json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing your JSON string wrong. use escape character.

**Ex:**

```
String s = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
```

for your code

```
String resp = "{\"message\":\"Error while updating\",\"success\":false}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a class representing your JSON input

```
public class Response {
    public String  message;
    public boolean success;
}
```

and use Google's `gson` library as follows to parse it

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(resp, Response.class);
System.out.println("Success: " + response.success);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you define `resp` properly and your code compiles.

I am also assuming your are using `org.json.JSONObject`

You will need to use `jObject.getBoolean("success").toString()`. I recall that `getString()` in JSONObject will throw exception if the field is not type of string.

Answer (score 0):

String resp = string output;

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resp);

System.out.println(object.get("message"));

System.out.println(object.get("success"));